# Does element order matter in web.xml?

Tags: java, xml, servlets, web.xml

When i tried the following code in servlet project,

```
  <servlet>
   <init-param>
     <param-name>a</param-name>
     <param-value>x</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <servlet-name>Result</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Result</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
```

it shows an error, but when I tried this,

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Result</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Result</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>a</param-name>
     <param-value>x</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </servlet>
```

there is no error.    Is there a predefined order?

Answer (score 2):

For web.xml, yes. The servlet XSD (or DTD if you're using an older version) requires that the elements be listed in a specific order.

Answer (score 2):

I assume, you are talking about `web.xml`, here is how you specify schema:

DTD

```xml
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
```

XML schema

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"      
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
```

So if you are familiar with XMLs, it should be easy for you to validate...

If not, you can read some [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/) another option is to use some tool...

Comment: The associated XSD:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd

Answer (score 1):

For the schema and dtd there is a specified order. If you reference them in your IDE it will show errors when they are out of order. However most J2EE containers do not verify your web.xml against a schema or dtd when parsing it so it will not cause errors when your .war/.ear is used.

You should try to keep them in the order specified as it is easier to locate things and make changes if they are grouped.

If you read the dtd/schema it will show the order. You can just download it from the URLs listed in other answers here.